# Getting data from checkbox as string to sql database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I get the value as string and use it as a param for my sp?

I'm working on a module that shows a list of accounts by editing a specific column using the checkbox and a button and that will open a new window of some sort by clicking the button and from their I can edit the specific column I want to change.

here is my code for the web

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static object List(string search, int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
{
    try
    {
        jtStartIndex = jtStartIndex + 1;
        var pageIndex = jtStartIndex > jtPageSize ? Math.Ceiling(decimal.Parse(jtStartIndex.ToString()) / decimal.Parse(jtPageSize.ToString())) : 1;
        IEnumerable<NewAccount> List= SortRecord(_repository.NewAccount.GetList(search, int.Parse(pageIndex.ToString()), jtPageSize), jtSorting);

        var totalRecord = List.Count() > 0 ? List.FirstOrDefault().totalRecord : 0;

        return new { Result = "OK", Records = List, TotalRecordCount = totalRecord };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

im using jtable there are more buttons here and there but this is only for the checkbox and the table

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#TableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'List',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'Id DESC',
    actions: {
        listAction: 'List.aspx/List'
    },
    fields: {
        Tag: {
            sorting: false,
            title: function (data) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="chkAll">';
            },
            width: '2.5%',
            display: function (data) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="chk">';
            }
        },
        ref_no: {
            title: 'Reference No.' ,
            width: '5%',
        },
        borrowerName: {
            title: 'Borrower Name'
        },
        lendingUnitDesc: {
            title: 'Lending Unit'
        },
        statusDesc: {
            sorting: false,
            title: 'Status',
            width: '4%'
        },
        rmName: {
            title: 'RM'
        },
        addedBy: {
            title: 'Owner'
        },
        SeniorReviewer: {
            title: 'Senior Reviewer'
        }
    },
})

$(".chkAll").click(function (event) {       
    if (this.checked) { 
        $(':checkbox').each(function () { 
            this.checked = true;            
        });
    } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () { 
            this.checked = false;                      
        });
    }
});
```

and here is the code for getting the value from the column using the checkbox

```
$("#btnReassign").button()
    .click(function () {
        var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="chk"]:checked');
        checkedBoxes.forEach(chk => {
            chk.closest("tr").querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)').forEach((td) => {
            });
        })
    });
```

here is the HTML part of my code

```
<div class="site-container" style="width:100%">
    <div id="SearchRecord" style="background-color:#DEEDF8; padding:3px; border:1px solid #DDDDDD; color:#2e6894">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Search Record : <input type="text" id="txtSearch" value="" size="40" />&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Filter"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="btnFilterby" value="Filter By RM/Lending Unit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="btnReassign" value="Reassign" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="hidden" id="lblValidation" style="color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold"/>
    </div>
    <div id="TableContainer" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hdnRefNo" class="hdnRefNo" value="0"/>
        <div class="div-RMpopup" style="width: 98%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div id="dvFilterModalPopUp"></div>
            <div id="dvReassignModalPopUp"></div>
        </div>
<br /><br />
```

I edit my question to include some of my codes to clarify somethings.

Comment: You tagged it as `jQuery`. Are you using the `jQuery` library? As the code is written in javascript.

Comment: Also could you pls add a sample HTML and clear out what you are trying to achieve with the above code? do you want `td:nth-child(2)` text?

Comment: hi, just edited my question and added some part of my codes. sorry for not giving and explaining it right away im not very good at speaking english.

Comment: pls, add the HTML part rendered on your browser, not the code part generating this HTML. You can get it by using the element tab of the inspect element. (right click on browser, click on inspect element and then click on element tab)

Comment: ive added the HTML part. im using jtable on my script for the table

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with relevant framework. We need to see a running example. I cannot use the jTable without adding a plugin from CDN, so please do that for me so I can help you further

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see some HTML

Let's break this down

Uncomment/comment whatever appropriate

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page has loaded
  document.getElementById('getInfo').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="chk"]:checked'); // all checked boxes
    const values = [...checkedBoxes].map(chk => {
      const checkedRow = chk.closest("tr");
      const cellWeWant = checkedRow.querySelectorAll('td')[2]
      const textWeWant = cellWeWant.textContent; // if the text
      const valueWeWant = cellWeWant.querySelector('input').value; // if the value of an input
      // return textWeWant; // uncomment to get text
      return valueWeWant;   // comment above and uncomment to get values 
    });
    console.log(values)
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
      <td>Line 1</td>
      <td>Description 1 <input type="text" value="value1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
      <td>Line 2</td>
      <td>Description 2 <input type="text" value="value2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
      <td>Line 3</td>
      <td>Description 3 <input type="text" value="value3" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="getInfo">Get info</button>
```

I tried to create a [mcve] from what you posted, but I think it is not the same jTable we are talking about here?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#TableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'List',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'Id DESC',
    actions: {
      listAction: 'List.aspx/List'
    },
    fields: {
      Tag: {
        sorting: false,
        title: function(data) {
          return '<input type="checkbox" class="chkAll">';
        },
        width: '2.5%',
        display: function(data) {
          return '<input type="checkbox" class="chk">';
        }
      },
      ref_no: {
        title: 'Reference No.',
        width: '5%',
      },
      borrowerName: {
        title: 'Borrower Name'
      },
      lendingUnitDesc: {
        title: 'Lending Unit'
      },
      statusDesc: {
        sorting: false,
        title: 'Status',
        width: '4%'
      },
      rmName: {
        title: 'RM'
      },
      addedBy: {
        title: 'Owner'
      },
      SeniorReviewer: {
        title: 'Senior Reviewer'
      }
    },
  })

  $(".chkAll").click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
      });
    } else {
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });
  $("#btnReassign").on("click", function() {
    var checkedBoxes = $('input[class="chk"]:checked'); // all checked boxes
    const values = [...checkedBoxes].map(function() {
      const $checkedRow = $(this).closest("tr");
      const $cellWeWant = $checkedRow.find('td').eq(2)
      const textWeWant = $cellWeWant.text(); // if the text
      const valueWeWant = $cellWeWant.find('input').val(); // if the value of an input
      // return textWeWant; // uncomment to get text
      return valueWeWant; // comment above and uncomment to get values 
    }).get();
    console.log(values)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jtable@2.6.0/lib/jquery.jtable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jtable@2.6.0/lib/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="site-container" style="width:100%">
  <div id="SearchRecord" style="background-color:#DEEDF8; padding:3px; border:1px solid #DDDDDD; color:#2e6894">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Search Record : <input type="text" id="txtSearch" value="" size="40" />&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Filter" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btnFilterby" value="Filter By RM/Lending Unit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btnReassign" value="Reassign" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="hidden" id="lblValidation" style="color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold" />
  </div>
  <div id="TableContainer" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hdnRefNo" class="hdnRefNo" value="0" />
<div class="div-RMpopup" style="width: 98%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="dvFilterModalPopUp"></div>
  <div id="dvReassignModalPopUp"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

Comment: Thank you for this, ive added the HTML part to further explain my project

Comment: I need an actual working code. Please see the comment I made earlier and the code I tried to make here